# PHP Showing Post if matches User Detail

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have generated this PHP below, so I want to say:-

If the User Registration Location matches the post location, then show that post to that user.

So e.g. If 'user_registration_location' equals the post taxonomy 'London' it will show the posts in london. I have created the below

```
  <?php if(get_field('user_registration_location') == the_field( 'user_registration_location', 'user_' . $current_user->ID )): ?>
      <?php foreach ( get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'location' ) as $tax ) {
            echo __( $tax->slug ) . ' ';
      }?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Could someone please advise how I can do this?

Plugins I am using are 'user registration plugin' and 'CPT UI'

Comment: are you using ACF plugin?

Comment: Why do you stop PHP and start PHP when it is not needed? Like this `?><?php`.

Comment: no using 'user registration plugin' and 'CPT UI'

Answer (score 1):

You will need to take the user meta and post meta. You should then do WP Query based on that.

(I was not sure what is your post location meta field called so I called it `location`)

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

if(isset($user_id)) {

  $user_location = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_registration_location');
  
  $args = array(
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'location',
          'value' => $user_location 
        )
      )
  );

  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  // The Loop
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ){ 
       $the_query->the_post();
       // Do Stuff
    }
  }

  // Reset Post Data
  wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Comment: Hi, would this work as I am calling the post taxonomy? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the answer - I got a bit sidetracked when I was writing it the first time. The `$args` is wp-query (https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/) so you can pass any taxonomy and other details.